# httpd -k start does nothing on Mac OS X and Syntax OK

Tags: macos, apache

I am trying to start apache2 httpd server on mac osx.  When I do, httpd doesnt seem to do anything.  This is how it looks on my terminal

```
Davids-MacBook-Pro:web david$ sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -t
Syntax OK
Davids-MacBook-Pro:web david$ sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
Davids-MacBook-Pro:web david$ ps auxww | grep httpd
david           14890   0.0  0.0  2423368    192 s000  R+    2:56PM   0:00.00 grep httpd
Davids-MacBook-Pro:web david$
```

Httpd seems not to be starting, and there are no reported errors.  My question is, how to I diagnose why httpd is not starting and how to fix it?

Comment: Normally httpd on Mac is started from launchd when you enable "web sharing" in system preferences.

Comment: No reported errors? You should at least get a startup message in the error_log (if the httpd can find it and write to it). Have you checked for core dumps?

Comment: Ah yes, there are lines in the error log.  Thank you, that explained it. `[Tue Feb 11 15:37:36 2014] [error] (2)No such file or directory: mod_mime_magic: can't read magic file /etc/apache2/conf/magic
[Tue Feb 11 15:37:36 2014] [error] (2)No such file or directory: could not open mime types config file /etc/mime.types.
Configuration Failed`